# How do you breed the Legendary monster?

Tags: tiny-monsters

There is a quest in the game to acquire the Legendary monster.  Description:

> **Legendary**
>
> Find and hatch the mysterious Legendary monster, master of the elements!
>
> [image: legendary monster image]

If you want to breed it, what combination of monsters do you use?

Comment: I see you saw the dragonvale clone too

Comment: Well do far I've Just got the fire plant and mountain to breed and I'll see how they do. To get the mountain you have to breed earth and ice monsters and for the fire plant you have to breed fire and plant monsters. I hope that helps and I'll get back to you on how it turns out.

Comment: Indeed.  Check the wiki description I wrote for it.

Comment: I have made a combination of all of the monsters to try and find the legendary monster.... First I did plant and earth, then with the child of that I combined it with fire, and then I combined that child with the ice monster, and now I'm gonna mix the child of that with the electric and see what happens. I doubt my method will work though. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been confirm [here](http://tinymonsters.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_Monster#comm-2643) and [here](http://www.gameteep.com/tiny-monsters/forum/solved-legendary-monster-breeding-guide/656744) that breeding **Flower and Mountain** has a rare chance to produce the legendary monster.  The first link involves a screen cap of the park and the second link includes a video, so I'm going to consider this definitive proof.  Since this combination is **Fire**/*Plant* + **Earth**/*Plant* it appears that previous theories about involving all elements are incorrect.  You do need to be level 22 to buy the habitat that the Legendary Monster lives in.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be on to level 22 to be able to hatch the legendary monster.

To hatch the monster you have to:

- Be on level 22
- Breed a teenage plant and an adult earth.

Then you will get a legendary monster.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to be level 22
2. Breed a teenage plant with an adult earth

Comment: Welcome to the site Francis!  Can you edit your answer to add a link to the source for the level 22 requirement?

Answer (score -1):

I got the legendary and the combos have to have the types plant and earth.

Comment: Hi Pat, welcome to the site.  Due the amount of speculation on this monster, could you please site a source or at least provide some proof that you have the monster?  It is easy with any Apple device to take a screen shot, simple press the square "home" button and the top "lock" button at the same time.  Then when you connect the device to your computer you can copy over the pictures from whichever device you are using (iPhone, iPad, iPod Touch, etc).

Answer (score -2):

Elements are earth electric ice fire get a hatching that will have all these Elements and you got your mystery monster

Comment: This is true but you missed some elements my friend