# What does a Level 9 Legendary Monster look like?

Tags: tiny-monsters

I just hatched a Legendary Monster and I was wondering if anyone has evolved theirs to level 9.   I'm level 33 and just curious to see if it has different Adult forms?

Comment: Relevant: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61843/how-do-you-breed-the-legendary-monster

Answer (score 1):

The level 9 (adult) Legendary Monster looks like this:

[image: Adult Legendary Monster]

Note that level 9 is no longer the final evolution of this monster.  It actually has a third evolution which converts it to one of the 9 possible Legacy Monster types.  See the tabbed section at the bottom of [this wiki article](http://tinymonsters.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_Monster) for more details on Legacy.